# align header text vertically next to an image

Tags: css, alignment, text-alignment

I am trying to align vertically header text next to an image. My problem is when I decrease the window width and the text wraps (height is higher than image height) it starts to align to the top of image

```css
.half {
  width: 50%;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="half">
  <div class="advantages_header">
    <img class="advantages_icon" src="http://placehold.it/90x90" />
    <h4>HEADER TEXT MAYBE LONG</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Need more explanation. As per my understanding if you write css for media query that will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Oh! I just figured out by myself, thanks for reading, I hope it will help someone :)

```css
.half {
  width: 50%;
}
.advantages_header {
  position: relative;
  height: 90px;
}
h4 {
  left: 110px;
  margin-right: 110px;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="half">
  <div class="advantages_header">
    <img class="advantages_icon" src="http://placehold.it/90x90" />
    <h4>HEADER TEXT MAYBE LONG</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```